# Calculating moments of a uniform distribution variable by fixing discontinuity of MGF.

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Given a continuous uniform distribution over $[0,1]$, the MGF is $$\frac{e^t-1}{t} $$. How come it's "allowed" to generate say the 1st moment by using a Taylor expansion? Why can the discontinuity (at $t=0$) be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: The value of the MGF, call it $\phi$, at $t=0$ is $1$ ($=\lim_{t\to 0}(e^t-1)/t$) so there is no discontinuity at $t=0$. You could use Taylor expansion or l'Hospital's Rule to find $\phi'(0)=\lim_{t\to 0}(\phi(t)-\phi(0))/t$.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes that's called a removable discontinuity, but still the function is not continuous at that point.